# WebClient download string (a few chars page) is so slow

Tags: c#, performance, webclient, downloadstring

I am trying to download a string from an URL. Unfortunately, it is very slow.

Here is my code:

```
    // One of these types for two bad solutions anyway
    // byte[] result = new byte[12];
    // string result;
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        String url = "http://bg2.cba.pl/realmIP.txt";
        //result = webClient.DownloadString(url); // slow as hell
        //webClient.OpenRead(url).Read(result, 0, 12); // even slower
    }
```

It takes about 4-5 seconds, which seems very inappropriate to me...

Content of this url is IP

```
 XX.YYY.ZZ.FF
```

Comment: Have you used Wireshark or something similar to see where the time is going?

Comment: I didn't use WS cuz I don't know how to operate with it

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek read into Wireshark then

Comment: I Just tested your code, it seems to work as fast as it should. Do you have a firewall or something in the middle ?

Comment: Ok i fixed this, I had to set Proxy as null :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed, sorry for putting this question here I guess, but... here is working code

```
string result;
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.Proxy=null;
    String url = "http://bg2.cba.pl/realmIP.txt";
    result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Just set Proxy to null

Comment: use `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` instead of null. read my answer for more details

Comment: I had to use " client.Proxy = null; " to make my code work faster. (C#)

Comment: webClient.Proxy=null; this is working for me

Answer (score 4):

It is clearly a problem with you line/pc/firewall

You can test it online:

http://goo.gl/XRqLjn

it takes about 500 milliseconds

[image]

**UPDATE after your own answer**

If you want to use no proxy you should use [GetEmptyWebProxy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection.getemptywebproxy(v=vs.110).aspx) as stated on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
webClient.Proxy=GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
```

Comment: Note: Even though `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` has become deprecated, this is the only way I was able to speed up the WebClient requests. If anyone knows any non-deprecated way of achieving the same behavior, please let me know.

Comment: they recommend to set .Proxy to "null" now

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and added some output to it.

```
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            String url = "http://bg2.cba.pl/realmIP.txt";
            timer.Stop();
            TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;
            String tex1 = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);


            timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            String result = webClient.DownloadString(url); // slow as hell
            timespan = timer.Elapsed;
            String tex2 = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);


            timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(url);
            timespan = timer.Elapsed;
            String tex3 = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);

            timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            byte[] result2 = new byte[12];
            int val = webClient.OpenRead(url).Read(result2, 0, 12); // even slower
            timespan = timer.Elapsed;
            String tex4 = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);

            textBox1.Text = result;
            t1.Text = tex1;
            t2.Text = tex2;
            t3.Text = tex3;
            t4.Text = tex4;
        }
```

with the following Result

[image]

Your code seems to be okay.
Check your Firewall and all the stuff that is involved