# WebClient very slow downloads

Tags: c#, performance, download, webclient

I am simply using `WebClient.DownloadString()` and it is outrageously slow. Maxing out at 40kbs I have tried setting the `WebClient.Proxy` to null which didn't work and i am not anywhere near maxing my internet speed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `webClient.Proxy=GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();`

See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603874/6550457

Comment: Or just 'webClient.Proxy = null;'

Answer (score 2):

Beside the working answer, It has an deprecated code, Here is the working updated code which is working with full speed for me:

```
client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

Hope it helps someone who doesn't want to use obsolete code!